# Use docker-compose to start test dependencies in gitlab

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to run system tests in my pipeline which depends on some running infrastructure (i.e. nifi, mongo-db, etc.). For my local tests I start those services with `docker-compose`. Now I would like to start those dependencies in the gitlab ci pipeline.

As far as I know gitlab services would be the perfect fit for that, but struggle with it because those services need some more configuration.

Because of that I used `docker-compose` directly inside the build like that:

```
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

image:
  name: docker/compose:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - start-dependencies
  - test

start-dependencies:
  script:
    - docker-compose down
    - docker-compose up -d

test:
  image: docker
  script:
    - docker run --rm -u gradle -v "$PWD":/home/gradle/project -w /home/gradle/project gradle gradle build
```

This does not work, because the docker network from the docker-compose call is not visible from the docker gradle build.

How can I spin up the required services for a gradle build with docker-compose?

Comment: You need to run all of these commands in the same gilab ci step. An other option as you mentioned would be to create your own image extending `compose:latest` that would spin up your compose project at start and declare it as a service. Note that the `compose` image should have pretty much the same tooling as the `docker` image so it should be ok to run your gradle build in there.